# Sort according to array in MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The MongoDB query:

```
data = Coll.objects().aggregate(
    {"$match": {"insert_time": {"$lt": to_datetime}}},
    {"$project": {"status": 1, "level: 1}},
    {"$sort": {"level": 1}})
```

Output:

```
{"status" : "Complete", "level" : "High" }
{"status" : "Incomplete", "level" : "Low" }
{"status" : "Complete", "level" : "Medium" }
```

The **level** array according to which the result should be sorted in MongoDB while sorting it in query:

```
level = ["High", "Medium", "Low"]
```

Expected output:

```
{"status" : "Complete", "level" : "High" }
{"status" : "Complete", "level" : "Medium" }
{"status" : "Incomplete", "level" : "Low" }
```

What changes are required in the Mongo query?

Answer (score 2):

Your sort will do a string alphabetical sort, so High,Low,Medium is expected.
You want an index(index on the array, first= max, last =minum) based sort.

Keep your query as it is(until project), and replace the sort with the 3 bellow stages(set/sort/unset), pick any solution of the 2.

Query

- `$indexOfArray` solution
- works for all array sizes

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zu6vaAFT_Bt)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"sort-key":
   {"$indexOfArray":[["High", "Medium", "Low"], "$level"]}}},
 {"$sort":{"sort-key":1}},
 {"$unset":["sort-key"]}])
```

Query

- `$cond` solution, works if you have small array, for 3 values its ok

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XiGQNfvvAk3)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"sort-key":
   {"$switch":
    {"branches":
     [{"case":{"$eq":["$level", "High"]}, "then":0},
      {"case":{"$eq":["$level", "Medium"]}, "then":1}],
     "default":2}}}},
 {"$sort":{"sort-key":1}},
 {"$unset":["sort-key"]}])
```

Schema change

With the current schema if you have alot of data sorting will be very slow.To make it fast you need to change your schema and make the sort-key part of you schema, and create index also on it.

For example your documents should be like

```
{"status" : "Complete", "level" : "High", "sort-key" 0 }
{"status" : "Complete", "level" : "Medium", "sort-key" 1 }
{"status" : "Incomplete", "level" : "Low", "sort-key" 2 }
```

With sort-key indexed and pre-calculated.